# Find Target to Call Dword Ptr in 16-bit Windows with IDA Pro

Tags: ida, windows

Looking for suggestions on steps that could be used to identify what code would get executed at call dword ptr es:[bx+0Ch] from static analysis.

```
cseg04:3044 loc_105D4:                              ; CODE XREF: cseg04:2F10↑j
    cseg04:3044                 push    0
    cseg04:3046                 push    34h ; '4'
    cseg04:3048                 les     bx, ppMalloc
    cseg04:304C                 push    es
    cseg04:304D                 push    bx
    cseg04:304E                 les     bx, es:[bx]
    cseg04:3051                 call    dword ptr es:[bx+0Ch]
    cseg04:3055                 add     sp, 8
    cseg04:3058                 mov     si, ax
    cseg04:305A                 mov     [bp-6], dx
    cseg04:305D                 or      dx, ax
    cseg04:305F                 jnz     short loc_105F8
```

ppMalloc section:

```
eg70:3612 ppMalloc        dd 0                    ; DATA XREF: cseg04:3048↑r
dseg70:3612                                         ; sub_145C0+24↑r ...
dseg70:3616 ; ATOM word_10CA26
dseg70:3616 word_10CA26     dw 0                    ; DATA XREF: sub_4637E:loc_463B1↑r
dseg70:3616                                         ; sub_4637E+3A↑r ...
dseg70:3618 word_10CA28     dw 0                    ; DATA XREF: sub_CE2A+1↑o
dseg70:3618                                         ; cseg03:2F9C↑o ...
dseg70:361A                 db    0
dseg70:361B                 db    0
dseg70:361C                 db    0
dseg70:361D                 db    0
dseg70:361E                 db    0
dseg70:361F                 db    0
dseg70:3620                 db    0
dseg70:3621                 db    0
dseg70:3622                 db    0
dseg70:3623                 db    0
dseg70:3624                 db    0
dseg70:3625                 db    0
dseg70:3626 unk_10CA36      db    0                 ; DATA XREF: sub_CE2A+A↑o
dseg70:3626                                         ; cseg03:2F93↑o ...
dseg70:3627                 db    0
dseg70:3628                 db    0
dseg70:3629                 db    0
dseg70:362A                 db    0
dseg70:362B                 db    0
dseg70:362C                 db    0
dseg70:362D                 db    0
dseg70:362E                 db    0
dseg70:362F                 db    0
dseg70:3630                 db    0
dseg70:3631                 db    0
dseg70:3632                 dw 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `ppMalloc` is a pointer to an instance of the [`IMalloc`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-imalloc) COM interface (e.g. it was initialized by a call to `CoGetMalloc`), which means the the first pointer in it (loaded by the `les` instruction) is the VTable which has the following methods.

First three are inherited from IUnknown, the parent of all COM objects:

---

+00 QueryInterface

+04 AddRef

+08 Release

---

Followed by the methods of IMalloc proper:

---

+0C [Alloc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-imalloc-alloc)

+10 DidAlloc

+14 Free

+18 GetSize

+1C HeapMinimize

+20 Realloc

---

So the code is probably calling `IMalloc::Malloc` to allocate 0x34 bytes, pointer to which is returned in the `ax:dx` register pair.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot deduce it from the fragment of code you have provided (unless we are @Igor Skochinsky of course). However, we can notice a few things:

- `ppMalloc` contains the address of dynamically allocated array of function pointers
- the function called by `call [bx+0Ch]` takes three arguments passed by stack: `0`, `34h` (offset?) and a pointer to the address of that dynamically allocated array (that is the address of `ppMalloc` pointer)
- at line `3051` `es:bx` points to the first element of that array and `es:[bx+0Ch]` is fourth element in it
- depending on the value returned (in `dx:ax`) the jump at the last line will or won't be performed (`or dx, ax` checks whether `dx:ax` is `0` or not)

If you have any doubts the comments to the disassembly given below should clarify them.

```
cseg04:3044                 push    0 ; push first argument
cseg04:3046                 push    34h ; '4' ; push the second one
cseg04:3048                 les     bx, ppMalloc ; es:bx = ppMalloc
cseg04:304C                 push    es
cseg04:304D                 push    bx ; push es:bx (ppMalloc)
cseg04:304E                 les     bx, es:[bx] ; es:bx = *ppMalloc (that is the value stored at dseg70:3612, i.e. pointer to array of function pointers, i.e. pointer to the first element of that array)
cseg04:3051                 call    dword ptr es:[bx+0Ch] ; call arrayOfFunctionPointers[3] - fourth entry as each entry is probably of dword size
cseg04:3055                 add     sp, 8 ; restore previous sp value
cseg04:3058                 mov     si, ax ; si = (returned result) % 2^16
cseg04:305A                 mov     [bp-6], dx ; [bp-6] = (returned result) / 2^16
cseg04:305D                 or      dx, ax ; will be 0 <=> (dx = 0 and ax = 0)
cseg04:305F                 jnz     short loc_105F8
```